# cant make a web page accept imported data from excel-vba

Tags: excel, vba, input, html

Any help with the below would be awesome...I'm using excel vba to upload a serial No into a web page and then clicking on a 'Check Warranty' button within the page which should then display more data, but when clicked, the input data in the search field disappears and a 'no product found..' error displayed. (works fine if I manually type/paste in and click the button)

```
Sub test()

Dim IE As New InternetExplorer
Dim Doc As HTMLDocument

IE.Visible = True

IE.navigate "https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/za/en/warrantylookup"

Do
 DoEvents
Loop Until IE.readyState = READYSTATE_COMPLETE

Set Doc = IE.document

Doc.getElementsByName("input_sn").Item("input_sn").Value = "PC0X5YHZ"

Doc.querySelector(".btn.btn-primary").Click

'should now take you to warranty detail page
'but just get error on web page "Sorry, no products were found that match that query......"


End Sub
```

[HTML Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IfHuX.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried clicking on the field before setting the value? Just setting the value in a filed doesn't always work as the page might not recognise the change in the field

Comment: Thanks. yes, nice idea, but have tried .click and pasted twice before pressing the button without success.

Comment: Firstly, try not pasting in the field. Type in the field. So click on it, then type on the field before pressing the button. If that doesn't work, you could try to trigger `OnChange` event before pressing the button

Comment: yes! that works! . added a .application.wait before the button click and manually added and removed a "space" from the end of the input field and it then worked!.  No luck with sending an automated keyboard event or even sendkeys yet. but thank you! :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Doc.getElementsByName("input_sn").Item("input_sn").Value = "PC0X5YHZ" 
Doc.getElementById("input_sn").Focus
SendKeys "z+{BS}", True
Doc.querySelector(".btn.btn-primary").Click
```

Answer (score 0):

The following works using selenium basic. After installing selenium remember to go VBE > Tools > References > Add reference to Selenium Type Library

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub EnterInfo()
    Dim d As WebDriver
    Set d = New ChromeDriver
    Const URL = "https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/warrantylookup"

    With d
        .Start "Chrome"
        .get URL
         .FindElementById("input_sn").SendKeys "pc0x5yhz"
         .FindElementByCss(".btn.btn-primary").Click

         Stop '<==Delete me later
        .Quit
    End With
End Sub
```

---

Cheating you can just use the redirect URL:

https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/gb/en/products/laptops-and-netbooks/thinkpad-x-series-laptops/thinkpad-x280-type-20kf-20ke/20ke/20kes5sd09/pc0x5yhz/warranty

As a plan B you might be able to scrape the machine type info to generate those URLs and then loop those URLs adding in the warranty info.

Comment: Thank you, unfortunately I don't have the  access rights to install and working on citrix platform...looks nice and easy in Selenium though :-)

Comment: It is easy with selenium.   Will you be doing this for lots of warranties?

Comment: yes ~20 per run so the cheat is not effective as it also pulls machine type info based on the input serial. Have the code ready to extract the data on the next page back into the report. So just this sticking block.

Comment: What I am getting at though is that you might be able to scrape the machine type info to generate those URLs and then loop those URLs. As a plan B that is. I will have a look again later today whether I can achieve anything with IE.

Comment: found the issue.. Zac suggested it required another trigger so added an application.wait command and manually tested by adding and removing a character from the end of the input field!.. just need to find a way to automate this keyboard event now.